# Windows 10 login issue after sleep

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, login

Whenever I sleep my laptop, and then I need to login, it seems that it won't accept my <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keyboard key, I also clicked the accept arrow button at the right side after the password field but the function won't work.


My keyboard and mouse are all working.

Now I really need to shutdown/restart my computer in order to login again but it is consuming too much time.


I think this problem is caused by the latest update because there is no problem since before that update, I updated my laptop last 19/12/2016.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop Windows from asking password after sleep:

1. Press the <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> key combination to open the Settings screen.
2. Click **Accounts**.
3. Click **Sign-in options** in the left side. Select **Never** under the
       Require sign-in section.

Comment: yes, it solves my problem temporarily, but i really need to secure a password whenever I leave my laptop because other people here will use unauthorized and that will be big problem when there is a sudden change in my laptop.

Comment: The issue you experienced seems to be an issue that Microsoft hasn't fixed yet. When you leave your laptop, you can press the Win+L shortcut keys to lock your PC, or sign out your account.